# How navbar-toggle, collapse, navbar-collapse classes work together?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to the world of CSS and Bootstrap 3.0.  Below is code which I can find at many places and now I can write it without any problem.  But I really don't know how things are working behind the scenes.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Company</a>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".top-nav">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse top-nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Above code will provide me a dynamic UI. Can someone answer my below queries

1. How connection is established between button and navbar. Ans: In
   this case I know class named 'top-nave' connect these two
   components. But then what is significance of other classes (
   collapse navbar-collapse ). I have learned that we need to have both
   the classes i.e. collapse and navbar-collapse.  Dont know why?
2. Is all magic done by CSS or we do have some javascript code that is
   manipulating code? ( I guess yes since there exists data- attribute)
3. Can anyone suggest other usage of data-toggle and data-target
   attribute in bootstrap 3 to understand concept clearly?

Regards,
Hemant

Comment: Why don't you read the docs on GetBootstrap.com http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: also, the collapse plugin is available in 2.x as well: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Nature of connection between button and navbar:

Through [collapse.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/collapse.js).  From the [v3 documentation,](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.0/docs/javascript/#collapse)

```
buttons show and hide another element via class changes:
.collapse hides content
Use a button with the data-target attribute and the data-toggle="collapse".
```

so in your code, `data-target=".top-nav"`

The classes `collapse` and `navbar-collapse` are significant for [the CSS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/search?l=CSS&q=navbar-collapse&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Both are needed to allow more specific selectors in the CSS.

**2.** The navbar collapses using javascript:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/collapse.js

**3.** The attributes [data-toggle](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=data-toggle&type=Code) and [data-target](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/search?p=1&q=data-target&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) are used throughout bootstrap for things like toggling visibility as discussed, but also in the carousel or to launch modals.

Answer (score 0):

This is far, far easier to fix now in **Bootstrap 4.x**. Just tweak the navbar class in your html like...

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

Mess with the **`navbar-expand-sm`**: Change ending -xs, -sm, -md, -lg, -xl, until the navbar collapses where you want it to. Took me a while on this so I thought I'd share :-)